# Pycharm type-hinting in __init__ does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, code-completion, type-hinting

I am using Python 2.7 and PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2.  I have the following snippet of code:

```
class ParentNode(node.Node):
    """ParentNode is a subclass of Node but also takes an additional child_nodes parameter.
    @type child_nodes: dict[str: child_node.ChildNode]
    """
    def __init__(self, name, node_type, FSPs, CTT_distributions, TMR_distributions,
                 prob_on_convoy, rep_rndstrm, child_nodes):
        """ParentNode is a subclass of Node but also takes an additional child_nodes parameter.
        @type child_nodes: dict[str: child_node.ChildNode]
        """
        node.Node.__init__(self, name, node_type, FSPs, CTT_distributions, TMR_distributions,
                           prob_on_convoy, rep_rndstrm)
        self.network_status = 'parent'
        self.child_nodes = child_nodes
```

The issue is that when I hover over `self.child_nodes` or `child_nodes`, the inferred type is shown as `Any` instead of `Dict[str, ChildNode]`. I don't understand why the typehinting I have in the docstring does not work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`dict[str: child_node.ChildNode]`

with

`dict[str, child_node.ChildNode]`